# How to call script automatically when email received?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail

I am writing a script that will automatically called when you receive email. It runs first first time when I execute it. Next time trigger should run it. But it gives me error.

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("parseEmailMessages(1)")
.timeBased()
.after(1 * 60 * 1000).create();

function parseEmailMessages(start) {

  start = start || 0;
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(start, 100);
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(
     'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y-DfkatwBrLHBpCMvd_Tc2Smhb87z6xrYVC78ulnMIo/edit#gid=231924366');

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      var tmp=null;
      message = threads[i].getMessages()[0];
      subject = message.getSubject();
      content = message.getPlainBody();

    if(subject=="Fwd: CREDIT APPLICATION"){

    if (content) {

      tmp = content.match(/First Name:\s*([A-Za-z0-9\s]*)(\r?\n)/);
      var fname = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No fname';

      tmp = content.match(/Last Name:\s*([A-Za-z0-9\s]+)(\r?\n)/);
      var lname = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No lname';

      tmp = content.match(/Address:\s*([A-Za-z0-9\s]+)(\r?\n)/);
      var address = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No address';

      tmp = content.match(/City:\s*([A-Za-z0-9\s]*)(\r?\n)/);
      var city = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No city';

      tmp = content.match(/State:\s*([a-zA-Z]+)*(\r?\n)/);
      var state = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No state';

       tmp = content.match(/Zip:\s*([0-9]*)(\r?\n)/);
      var zip = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No zip';

      tmp = content.match(/Cell Phone Number:\s*([0-9]*[-]*[0-9]*[-]*[0-9]*)(\r?\n)/);
      var cphone = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No cphone';

      tmp = content.match(/Email:\s*([A-Za-z0-9@.]+)(\r?\n)/);
      var email = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No email';

      tmp = content.match(/Own:\s*([A-Za-z]*)(\r?\n)/);
      var proptype = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1] : 'No proptype';

      tmp = content.match(/Mortgage:\s*([$][0-9]*[,]*[0-9]*[,][0-9]*[.][0-9]*)*(\r?\n)/);
      var rent = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No rent';

      tmp = content.match(/Years at Address:\s*([0-9]+\s[year(s)]+\s*[0-9]+\s*[month(s)]+)(\r?\n)/);
      var yearatadd  = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No yearatadd';  
    //Employee info
      tmp = content.match(/Employer Name:\s*([A-Za-z0-9\s]+)(\r?\n)/);
      var empname = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No empname';

      tmp = content.match(/Position:\s*([A-Za-z0-9\s]+)(\r?\n)/)
      var emptitle = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No emptitle';

      tmp = content.match(/Phone:\s*([0-9]*[-]*[0-9]*[-]*[0-9]*)(\r?\n)/);
      var bphone = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No bphone';

      tmp = content.match(/Gross Monthly Salary:\s* ([$][0-9]*[,]*[0-9]*[,][0-9]*[.][0-9]*)*(\r?\n)/);
      var salary = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No salary';

      tmp = content.match(/Years at Employment:\s*([0-9]+\s[year(s)]+\s*[0-9]+\s*[month(s)]+)(\r?\n)/);
      var empyear  = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No empyear';
      //Vehicl info
      tmp = content.match(/Make:\s*([A-Za-z]+\s*[-]*\s*[A-Za-z]*)*(\r?\n)/);
      var make = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No make';

      tmp = content.match(/Model:\s*([A-Za-z0-9\s]*)*(\r?\n)/);
      var model = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No model';

      tmp = content.match(/Exterior Color:\s*([A-Za-z0-9\s]*)*(\r?\n)/);
      var extcolor = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No extcolor';

      tmp = content.match(/Interior Color:\s*([A-Za-z0-9\s]*)*(\r?\n)/);
      var intcolor = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No intcolor';     

      tmp = content.match(/Vehicle Year:\s*([A-Za-z0-9\s]*)*(\r?\n)/);
      var vehyear = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No vehyear';

      tmp = content.match(/DownPayment:\s* ([$][0-9]*[,]*[0-9]*[,][0-9]*[.][0-9]*)*(\r?\n)/);//"37 year(s) 00 month(s)" "Pension" 
      var downpay= (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No downpay';

      sheet.appendRow([fname,lname,address,city,state,zip,cphone,email,proptype,rent,yearatadd,empname,emptitle,bphone,salary,empyear,make,model,extcolor,intcolor,vehyear,downpay]);


    }//subject if
    } // End if

  } // End for loop
}
```

Can you help me. Thanks

Comment: What is the error that it gives you the second time? It could contain helpful info as to what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a one-time trigger that will run 1 minute after the script is run. What you need is a repeat trigger that auto-runs every n minutes.

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("parseEmailMessages")
.timeBased().everyMinutes(5).create();
```

In either cases, the script will not auto-run when an email is received. You need to maintain some sort of mark for emails that have already been processed else they will be logged into the sheet multiple times. A good option would be mark emails with a particular label and then ignore these emails in the next search iteration.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how I would label and ignore emails that already been writen to spreadsheet.